# How to get Row data as a new column header with postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, pivot, crosstab

I have a following data set

"select * from table1"

result:

**Contract_Code**, **Location_Name**, **Valid_Quantity**, **Category**, **Values**

"BAJRA","ALWAR",100,"DAMAGED IMMATURE SHRIVELED GRAINS",5

"BAJRA","ALWAR",100,"FOREIGN MATTER",1

"BAJRA","ALWAR",100,"IMMATURE GRAINS",3

"BAJRA","ALWAR",100,"INORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER",0

"BAJRA","ALWAR",100,"MOISTURE (%) BY WEIGHT",12

"BAJRA","ALWAR",100,"ORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER",1

"BAJRA","ALWAR",100,"WEEVILLED GRAIN",0

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"DAMAGED IMMATURE SHRIVELED GRAINS",5

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"FOREIGN MATTER",1

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"IMMATURE GRAINS",1

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"INORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER",0

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"MOISTURE",13

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"MOISTURE (%) BY WEIGHT",13

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"ORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER",1

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"OTHER EDIBLE GRAINS",1

"BAJRA","DAUSA",1621,"WEEVILLED GRAIN",0

"BAJRA","JAIPUR",820,"DAMAGED IMMATURE SHRIVELED GRAINS",4

"BAJRA","JAIPUR",820,"DAMAGED SHRIVELLED GRAINS",3

"BAJRA","JAIPUR",820,"FOREIGN MATTER",1

"BAJRA","JAIPUR",820,"IMMATURE GRAINS",2

"BAJRA","JAIPUR",820,"INORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER",0

"BAJRA","JAIPUR",820,"MOISTURE",13

"BAJRA","JAIPUR",820,"MOISTURE (%) BY WEIGHT",13

I want the output as:

**CONTRACT_CODE, LOCATION_NAME, VALID_QUANTITY, DAMAGED IMMATURE SHRIVELED GRAINS, DAMAGED SHRIVELLED GRAINS, FOREIGN MATTER, IMMATURE GRAINS, INORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER, MOISTURE, MOISTURE (%) BY WEIGHT, ORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER, OTHER EDIBLE GRAINS, WEEVILLED GRAIN**

"BAJRA", "ALWAR" ,100,5,1,3,0,null,12,1,null,0,null

"BAJRA", "DAUSA", 1621,null,5,1,1,null,0,13,13,1,1

"BAJRA", "JAIPUR", 820,4,3,1,null,null,2,0,13,13,null

basically my 4th column "Category" is to be displayed as number of distinct values as columns.
and 5th column "Values" is the values for each of the row entries (column). It can be null if the category is absent for the combination of the first 3 columns (CONTRACT_CODE, LOCATION_NAME, VALID_QUANTITY).

Comment: It looks like you are trying to perform a join with another table but you haven't given enough information about the second table involved, you just gave the first table and the result without including details about where the additional information is stored.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can get what you want. What you are wanting is a Pivot Table, well that is not something SQL is good at doing. You would be much, much better off to just run:

```
select Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity, Category, sum(values) 
  from test1 
 group by Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity, Category 
 order by Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity, Category;
```

This gets all the data and values your final presentation needs. Then turn those results over to your apps presentation manager to build the pivoted  presentation.  
But if you must have the presentation prepared by SQL then the above simple query above becomes the monster: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3714578361759fe510b703743180ac0ec))

```
select Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity 
      , max ("DAMAGED IMMATURE SHRIVELED GRAINS")  "DAMAGED IMMATURE SHRIVELED GRAINS"                                                 
      , max ("DAMAGED SHRIVELLED GRAINS")          "DAMAGED SHRIVELLED GRAINS"         
      , max ("FOREIGN MATTER")                     "FOREIGN MATTER"                    
      , max ("IMMATURE GRAINS")                    "IMMATURE GRAINS"                   
      , max ("INORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER")           "INORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER"          
      , max ("MOISTURE")                           "MOISTURE"                          
      , max ("MOISTURE (%) BY WEIGHT")             "MOISTURE (%) BY WEIGHT"            
      , max ("ORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER")             "ORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER"            
      , max ("OTHER EDIBLE GRAINS")                "OTHER EDIBLE GRAINS"               
      , max ("WEEVILLED GRAIN")                    "WEEVILLED GRAIN"                   
   from (  
          select Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity 
               , case when category = 'DAMAGED IMMATURE SHRIVELED GRAINS'  then sumvalues else null end   "DAMAGED IMMATURE SHRIVELED GRAINS"                                                                                               
               , case when category = 'DAMAGED SHRIVELLED GRAINS'          then sumvalues else null end   "DAMAGED SHRIVELLED GRAINS"          
               , case when category = 'FOREIGN MATTER'                     then sumvalues else null end   "FOREIGN MATTER"                     
               , case when category = 'IMMATURE GRAINS'                    then sumvalues else null end   "IMMATURE GRAINS"                    
               , case when category = 'INORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER'           then sumvalues else null end   "INORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER"           
               , case when category = 'MOISTURE'                           then sumvalues else null end   "MOISTURE"                           
               , case when category = 'MOISTURE (%) BY WEIGHT'             then sumvalues else null end   "MOISTURE (%) BY WEIGHT"             
               , case when category = 'ORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER'             then sumvalues else null end   "ORGANIC FOREIGN MATTER"             
               , case when category = 'OTHER EDIBLE GRAINS'                then sumvalues else null end   "OTHER EDIBLE GRAINS"                
               , case when category = 'WEEVILLED GRAIN'                    then sumvalues else null end   "WEEVILLED GRAIN"                       
            from ( 
                    select Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity, Category, sum(values)  sumvalues  
                     from test1 
                     group by Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity, Category
                 ) sq1
       ) sq2   
 group by Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity 
 order by Contract_Code, Location_Name, Valid_Quantity;
```

**BTW:** If a new category comes along you have to rewrite the query, otherwise the query will simply just throw the data away. This should not be necessary allowing your presentation manager to handle the pivoting. It simply(?) the number on `Categories` in the result set and adjusts accordingly. SQL cannot do that (well there is a way, but it makes the pivoting look super simple, so I won't go there).  

**Take away:** Just because you extract the data with SQL, does not mean that SQL is the appropriate tool for complete process. Use the appropriate tool/language for the task.